# Rest API design multiple URLs to same resource?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

In my API I have the following resource:

```
example.com/api/v1/users/me/sites
example.com/api/v1/users/123/sites
```

Which returns all sites for the current or given user.

Now, what if I want to fetch all sites, and ignore users.
I'd assume that would have the following URL:

```
example.com/api/v1/sites
```

Which then strikes me as somewhat odd to have sites as a root resource and as a subresource for users.

Is this an OK approach or is it common to do this some other way?

Or should it be something like:

```
example.com/api/v1/users/sites
```

Where there is no Id for the users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with having

```
example.com/api/v1/sites
```

In addtion to

```
example.com/api/v1/users
```

especially each seems to be a root aggregate.

So if association is **composition** rather than **aggregation** (between site and user) then it is not only OK, but also correct to have them as the root URL fragment.

Answer (score 3):

For me, as a rule of thumb, I look at what I'm returning from the API and this usually informs what I'm representing.

For example, you are actually returning sites, not users for the URL: example.com/api/v1/users/123/sites.  In this case, I would prefer to address sites, as that is what is being returned.

So, I would opt for this URL: **example.com/api/v1/sites?user=123**

IMHO, this is utilizing the query string as an actual query for sites.

So, for the site representation I would build it up like this:

1. All sites: **example.com/api/v1/sites**
2. A particular site: **example.com/api/v1/sites/1**
3. A user's site: **example.com/api/v1/sites?user=123**
4. Current user's site: **example.com/api/v1/sites?user=current**

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add something to this interesting question.

You could for example find out which user "owns" a certain site by doing

```
example.com/api/v1/sites/[site_id]/user
```

This would return the user resource that owns site with site_id.

Another example could be users and addresses. If you allow users to share an address resource (addresses can have several users) you could do this:

`example.com/api/v1/users/[user_id]/address` => returns address for user with user_id. Doing a `DELETE` operation on that path will not delete the whole address resource but merely the connection between the user and the address. To delete the address itself you should do `DELETE` on `example.com/api/v1/addresses/[address_id]`

`example.com/api/v1/addresses/[address_id]/users` => returns users that live at that address and similarly as deleting the address from a user you can also delete a user from an address with `DELETE` on `example.com/api/v1/addresses/[address_id]/users/[user_id]`

The relationship between Address and User (what @Aliostad refers to as association as composition) itself is a resource and can be accessed and also deleted without deleting the resources themselves.